# IPN Delivery Failed:I/O error

Tags: paypal-ipn

been trying to wrap my head around an issue I have with the IPN tester, not 100% sure if its my hosting company's problem or Paypal Developer 'beta' to be honest but my IPN's have worked fine on a few sites I have for atleast a year and now it doesn't on any of them. I've not changed anything and now im getting

IPN Delivery Failed:I/O error: www.mywebsitesname.co.uk; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: www.mywebsitesname.co.uk

and none of my NotifyUrl.ashx handlers are working.

any ideas what this actually means in english? any more info. from me required to help you diagnose my issue?

#

AS AN UPDATE (27-08-2013), I thought I would try out the original C# SDK sample code from Paypal that I used to set up my IPN's with about a year or three ago (ie. it worked great with the IPN simulator). I have put it onto two different hosting companies servers to check its not an issue with a particular hosting server and my results using the IPN Simulator show "error 500: internal server error" for one and "IPN Delivery Failed:I/O error: www.ang##########.co.uk; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: www.ang############.co.uk".

In short, I have the same identical sample file from Paypal (that used to work) in the root of each hosting companies servers and im using the same IPN simulator settings, with the exception of the IPN handler URL has the webaddress of the server followed by '/Handler.ashx' (which is the handler file) but i'm getting different errors.

Also to make this a bit more interesting, today I correctly received an IPN from Paypal to one of the same hosting server webaddress, with a 'transaction_subject : PayPal money request from xxxxxxxx' which was received and processed by my existing IPN handler (not the sample one from Paypal) and returned the correct info. to receive 'IPN Response: VERIFIED DateTime: 27-08-2013 19:05' so this got through and worked fine.

So in conclusion, I wonder if Paypal have either changed something and not informed the community or have an issue with their IPN simulator / CART IPN. If anyone can help or if a Paypal support engineer would like to work with me to try out some code, etc, please get back to me as I will keep trying to solve this but to be honest I see not what else I can do from my end as I've seen working IPN and a non working IPN simulator.

As extra info. here is an IPN Message as from my sandbox seller test account, that can't get through to my IPN handler on one of the same hosting servers (returns error 500) yet this used to get through and nothing has changed.

'mc_gross=2.75&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&address_status=confirmed&item_number1=BabyGrow2&payer_id=KHJGBQZNAFB7L&tax=0.00&address_street=1 Main St&payment_date=14:34:07 Aug 27, 2013 PDT&payment_status=Pending&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=95131&mc_shipping=0.00&mc_handling=0.00&first_name=Test&mc_fee=0.28&address_country_code=US&address_name=Test Buyer&notify_version=3.7&custom=1csi4t45gy4gkz45r5r4t0ey&payer_status=verified&business=wow####gmail.com&address_country=United States&num_cart_items=1&mc_handling1=0.00&address_city=San Jose&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A1fBAmiE5lcDRsQKQNaqoyQI7ucQ&payer_email=wow######@gmail.com&mc_shipping1=0.00&tax1=0.00&txn_id=8SG98957G0030294Y&payment_type=instant&last_name=Buyer&address_state=CA&item_name1=Baby Grow Age 0 - 1&receiver_email=wow########@gmail.com&payment_fee=&quantity1=1&receiver_id=8QRMB3QFHCL56&pending_reason=paymentreview&txn_type=cart&mc_gross_1=2.75&mc_currency=GBP&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&transaction_subject=1csi4t45gy4gkz45r5r4t0ey&payment_gross=&ipn_track_id=7b4507c8c4313'

Still hoping we can resolve this soon.

Many Thanks.
Trev.

Asp.net / C# / HTML / CSS3

Comment: UPDATE (30-09-2013): Spoken to one of the server support techs and he informed me that for my handler.aspx file to write to a log file I would need write access set for my handler file, this is what I had an idea it might be from the 500Error, but nothing I could personally do anything about. Its to do with protecting against Viruses writing/ replecating on servers (and rightly so).

Comment: ...So, back to the IPN simulator issue, is there one? the facts don't lie, I now am able to use a sandbox test account and a live account to write an IPN to and receive from two different servers from two different websites (one of which is live and happily receiving payments) yet the IPN simulator to the same test handler file gives "IPN Delivery Failed:Cannot extract response: no Content-Type found". So im still wondering if its a port issue, or because its only a US setup,. Anyone else?